# How to 301 Redirect old dynamic URLs to their relevant New dynamic URLs in .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

Old urls structure: http://www.statebankofindiaifsccode.com/state-bank-of-india-sbi-ifsc-code/assam

in above url after this folder /state-bank-of-india-sbi-ifsc-code/

values are dynamic, like they are states generated dynamically.

New Urls Structure : http://www.statebankofindiaifsccode.com/state-bank-of-india/assam

For all dynamic urls above with different states i want them to redirect to new url structure like shown above.

My current htaccess code:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)-sbi-ifsc-code/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ /bankdetails-state.php?bankfromhtac=$1&statefromhtac=$2

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)-sbi-ifsc-code/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ /bankdetails-state.php?bankfromhtac=$1&statefromhtac=$2
```

Please help me i tried many combinations using, Redirect 301, RedirectMatch etc.

But nothing works for me. I checked other related questions but don't find similar pattern redirects.

Please suggest 301 redirect using .htaccess only, since it will be useful for SEO.

Comment: Do you already have your new rewriterules working? Could you add those as well?

Answer (score 1):

Replace your rules with these rules:

```
RewriteEngine On

# old URL to new URL redirect
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)-sbi-ifsc-code/([\w-]+)/?$ /$1/$2 [L,NC,NE,R=302]

# internal handler for new URI scheme
RewriteRule ^(state-bank-of-india)/([\w-]+)/?$ bankdetails-state.php?bankfromhtac=$1&statefromhtac=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help, it's working, can i change 302 to 301 in this line RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)-sbi-ifsc-code/([\w-]+)/?$ /$1/$2 [L,NC,NE,R=302] is it SEO friendly?

Comment: Yes definitely you can use 301 now.